# Problem with Write Custom Function in reportViewer repot

Tags: reportviewer

I want to use of a custom function in  reportviewer's expression report .
I wrote this function in code tab section in report's property.
I want to use  of this function in my feild's expression but when i write "Code" and put after that "." , intellisense in report's expression  does not show me my function.

```
   Public Function FarsiNumber(ByVal str As String) As String
         Dim s As String = ""
         Dim ch() As Char = str.ToCharArray
            For Each c In ch
                If IsNumeric(c) Then
                  s += CChar(ChrW(1728 + CInt(AscW(c))))
                Else
                    s += c.ToString
                End If
              Next
         Return s
  End Function
```

any body can show me an example. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intellisense doesn't catch my custom functions either. But you can still use them.
In your case, you can use Code.FarsiNumber() in your expressions in your report